# How to unpack dictionary values to a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to write a script that grabs data from an API, transforms it and then passes to Google Sheets for reporting purposes.
I am stuck on a call that returns the data as a dictionary.  I've unpacked dictionaries to DataFrames before but I am stuck on this - I just can't get my head around the format and how to unpack it.

The data is coming out like this

```
{None: {'transfers': {'1': {'rows': [{'pointOfSaleID': 1,
      'initialAmount': '£0.00',
      'opened': 'xxx, 26/11/2018 08:16',
      'dayIncome': '£0.00',
      'cashTotal': '£0.00',
      'cashExpected': '£0.00',
      'closed': 'xxx, 26/11/2018 19:44',
      'banked': '£0.00',
      'left': '£0.00',
      'totalCounted': '£0.00',
      'difference': '£0.00',
      'varianceReason': '',
      'totalTransactions': 4},
     {'pointOfSaleID': 2,
      'initialAmount': '£0.00',
      'opened': 'xxx, 26/11/2018 07:54',
      'dayIncome': '£254.81',
      'cashTotal': '£254.81',
      'cashExpected': '£254.81',
      'closed': 'xxx, 26/11/2018 20:26',
      'banked': '£0.00',
      'left': '£0.00',
      'totalCounted': '£0.00',
      'difference': '-£254.81',
      'varianceReason': '',
      'totalTransactions': 47},
```

And I want to pass it into a DataFrame that has the keys as a single set of column headers (ie `'pointofSaleID', 'initialAmount', 'opened', 'dayIncome', 'cashTotal', 'cashExpected'`...) and the rows as the data values(ie 1, '£0:00', '£0:00'...).

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_name["transfers"]["1"]["rows"])`? - Also best not to use `dict` as the variable name for your dictionary as it clobbers the builtin